# Inserting slash into CSS

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to add font-awesome unicode into my CSS using PHP.
I'm trying to achieve:
content: "\f001"; for example.

I'm able to add the "f001" part wihout issue, but the starting "\" is causing me headaches.

With PHP, I'm unable to echo the \ character before without adding a space after it.

I've searched for a solution everywhere but cannot overcome this.

Here is an example where I'm displaying the value:

```
content: "<?php echo $bkpk_fa_code; ?>";
```

That will produce the unicode value so the result will be:

```
content: "f001';
```

But of course, I need the \ before it.

I've tried many different variations to get the desired output of "\f001" with no luck.

Can anyone pride the solution to do this?

Best Regards,

Comment: double escaping the backslash ?

Comment: is the filename .css or a .php file extension?

Comment: The problem is with the statement that assigns to the variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put the backslash outside of the PHP echo.

```
content: "\<?php echo $bkpk_fa_code; ?>";
```

If you want to use the backslash inside of the echo you may escape it.

```
content: "<?php echo '\\' . $bkpk_fa_code; ?>";
```

Comment: How so basic of me...
i had done the first example you provided, but DreamWeaver tells me it is not correct (of course - gotta change editors some day), so I had backed out.
Thanks Dave.

Answer (score 0):

this will echo "\f001";

```
<?php $bkpk_fa_code='f001';?>

content: "\<?php echo $bkpk_fa_code; ?>";
```

alternately

```
content: "<?php echo '\\'.$bkpk_fa_code; ?>";
```

ohh..dave and I am editing answer with few seconds difference...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the variable contains the backslash:

```
$bkpk_fa_code = '\f001';
```

Don't use double quotes around the string, as backslash is treated as an escape prefix inside double quotes and would have to be doubled. See [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Dave gave the right solution. I did not want to add the \ before because I'm having the client copy the unicode from the Font-Awesome 5 website directly. The website does not include the \ before when you copy the unicode.